# Android Cardview elements stack on top of each other

Tags: android, material-design, android-cardview

I have a `cardview` layout like the one showed below, but both of the elements in my file stack on top of each other. I've read other posts that say to be able to space elements more efficiently you have to have another layout inside the `cardview`, but it's not working for me. If I add a `android:layout_above...` then one of the elements disappears. I want to one element above the other. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/currentData"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/orange">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/cardviewLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            tools:text="this is the time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/temperature"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/temperature"
            tools:text="50°"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: So you want time to fill half top of the cardview and temperature the other half?

Comment: Not necessarily half and half. Just one above the other

Comment: @ralphi9225 check my updated answer, with the anchorview trick you can play with margin, and layout height to achieve more flexible view

Comment: https://github.com/amyu/StackCardLayoutManager try this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout for that

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/currentData"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/orange">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/cardviewLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            tools:text="this is the time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/temperature"
            android:weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/temperature"
            tools:text="50°"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:weight="1"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

or if you want to use RelativeLayout you can use this trick

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/currentData"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/orange">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/cardviewLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/anchor_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            tools:text="this is the time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/anchor_view"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/temperature"
            tools:text="50°"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/anchor_view"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

This way the anchorview will be located in the middle of the parent view but won't be drawed because the width and the height is zero but it will be come the reference for time and temperature so time will fill the upper half and temperature will fill the bottom half